# Laravel 4.2 translator custom key

Tags: laravel, localization

Here's a snippet from the messages.php translation file:

```
return array(
   ...
   'foo.0' => 'Fooooo',
   'fake'  => 'Not original'
);
```

I'm trying to get a translation by key using `Lang::get('messages.foo.0')`, but it returns `'foo.0'`. If I call `Lang::get('messages.fake')` it returns `'Not original'` as expected. Does somebody have an idea how get the 'foo.0' key using `Lang::get()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to modify the way your array is setup for it to work correctly.

```
return array(
    'foo' => array(
        '0' => 'Foooo'
    ),
    'fake'  => 'Not original'
);
```